# Excel: How to calculate the sum product with multiple conditions?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My table looks like this:
[image]

As you can see the there is a rate chart and distribution of Staff among different levels. What I need is a table with the total rate for each staff. For example, if you take staff C, you can see he is in Cat2 with 2 times in L1U and 3 times in L1L Cat2; also Cat1 for 3 times in L2L. So the total amount for C will be:

```
Level&Cat    Rate    Count    Subtotal
L1U-Cat2      15      2          30
L1L-Cat2      17      3          51
L2L-Cat1      35      3          105  == Total = 105+51+30 =>186
```

So the final output will be:

```
Staff Name       Total
A              Need calculation
B              Need calculation
C                 186
D              Need calculation
...                ....
```

How can this be possible? Now I am using Count if but for each row and column so it is almost like  51 columns long for each level and category and the calculation threading gives a lot of lag because of this.

What formula can I use?

Comment: What version of excel are you using? I'm thinking that if you had the levels in alphabetical order (L1L,L1U,L2L,L2U...) then you could try using Lookup or Xlookup or Index/match or possibly vlookup with the assumption that search keys are in order so it does a fast lookup.

Comment: Perhaps sumproduct() with a logic test for the same name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution with three helper columns `K:M`.

[image]

## Formulas

- `K3` `=INDEX($A$2:$D$12,MATCH($F3,$A$2:$A$12,0),MATCH(G$2,$A$2:$D$2,0))`. It looks up the rate for the given combination of *Level* and *Category*. It would not be necessary to use the `MATCH` formula, but it is more robust this way.
- `P3` `=SUMIFS($K$3:$M$14,$G$3:$I$14,O3)` just sums up the rates per each category for the given *staff name*. (Revised based on Naresh's comment)

Comment: @Naresh: Thank you so much! I revised the answer to incorporate your solution.

Answer (score 2):

**Without helper column**

We can wrap Qualia's brilliant answer in one array (CSE - Control+Shift+Enter) function like below

```
=SUM(IF($G$3:$I$14=K3,INDEX($B$3:$D$12,N(IF(1,MATCH($F$3:$F$14,$A$3:$A$12,0))),N(IF(1,MATCH($G$2:$I$2,$B$2:$D$2,0))),1)))
```

As suggested by Mark Fitzpatrick in the comments below we can also use following formula.

```
=SUM(INDEX($B$3:$D$12,N(IF(1,MATCH($F$3:$F$14,$A$3:$A$12,0))),N(IF(1,MATCH($G$2:$I$2,$B$2:$D$2,0))),1)*($G$3:$I$14=K3))
```

Copy the formula. Press F2 in L3 cell. Paste the formula and press Control+Shift+Enter. Copy that cell to L4:L6

[image]

**Explanation**

We can create an array of K3:M14 in Qualia's answer using array function

```
=INDEX($B$3:$D$12,N(IF(1,MATCH($F$3:$F$14,$A$3:$A$12,0))),N(IF(1,MATCH($G$2:$I$2,$B$2:$D$2,0))),1)
```

Then we can wrap this in Sum(if..) as mentioned above.

Refer [this Exceljet](https://exceljet.net/formula/return-array-with-index-function) link for `N(IF..)` function.

Comment: I was thinking along the same lines as you and Qualia. I guess the N()'s are needed if the Excel version is pre 2016, otherwise you could do: `=SUM( INDEX($B$3:$D$12, MATCH($F$3:$F$14,$A$3:$A$12,0), MATCH($G$2:$I$2,$B$2:$D$2,0)) * ($G$3:$I$14=K3))` but what does adding an Area do in your array formula?

Comment: @markfitzpatrick I tried it without N(If...) but it was not giving me sum. So, I referred to the given exceljet link. Try this `SUM(INDEX($B$3:$D$12,MATCH($F$3:$F$14,$A$3:$A$12,0),MATCH($G$2:$I$2,$B$2:$D$2,0),1))` .. It did not give 825 ... In short, the formula should give us total for that array. But it was giving me only the first element value 31. .. The formula you have given returns 248

Comment: Hi @markfitzpatrick .. With N(IF..) wrap in Index formula .. Your formula works like this .. `=SUM(INDEX($B$3:$D$12,N(IF(1,MATCH($F$3:$F$14,$A$3:$A$12,0))),N(IF(1,MATCH($G$2:$I$2,$B$2:$D$2,0))),1)*($G$3:$I$14=K3))` .. Happy to learn that .. Can I incorporate it in the answer? Thank you.

Comment: Sure @Naresh - I learned something from you as well. :-)